# Visual Studio: running project output as a post-buid event

Tags: visual-studio-2008, java-native-interface, post-build-event

I have a project that runs its output as a post-build event. Also this application uses JNI functions and thus needs to load `jvm.dll` (it is loaded automatically using `jvm.lib`).

- I can build and run my program normally in visual studio.
- I can also run the executable by double clicking it.
- I can run it using the command line.

However if I enter the same command line as a post-build event I get the following error:

> This application has failed to start because jvm.dll was not found.
>   Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

I have added the path to jvm.dll to my PATH environment variable already. I'm not sure why it cannot find it.

Comment: Make sure your `PATH` is pointing to the correct `jvm.dll`.  There may be more than one on your system.  [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) can show you where your command-line execution is picking it up.

Comment: @technomage As expected dependency walker only shows that a file named `jvm.dll` is missing. I tried full paths option and it's still the same file name. `PATH` variable is set correctly. It is set as system environment variable not a user variable so I think every program should be able to see it. Is there a way to override this value in windows? Where should I look for it?

Comment: Perhaps it's a 32- vs 64-bit issue?  Dump the environment from your command line and compare to a similar dump from your post-build event command line.

Comment: @technomage I'm on a 32-bit system and have installed a 32-bit JDK. So I think there should not be any 32-vs-64-bit issues. I'm not sure what you mean by dumping the environment from command line, can you please explain?

Comment: @technomage Actually I think I tried what you said. Printing env vars resulted in a different PATH string than the one defined on my system. Apparently VS changes that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to technomage for helping me find the solution.

Apparently VS manipulates environment variables in its context. So I just had to set it again in the post-build event using the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path_to_jvm.dll
"$(TargetPath)"
```